# Cloudformation template to create an eventrule that calls a stepfunction when new row is added to dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: CloudFormation stack for EventBridge rule triggering a Step Function on DynamoDB PutItem

Resources:
  EventBridgeRole789:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: EventBridgeRole789
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: events.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: EventBridgeInvokeStepFunctionPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - states:StartExecution
                Resource: !Sub arn:aws:states:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stateMachine:${StateMachineName}

  CloudTrailRole789:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: CloudTrailRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CloudTrailPermissions
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:280127465923:log-group:kjgfdxpoikiuuuji-MyEventRuleLogGroup789-ccWZ1hbXC6M6:*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:GetBucketAcl
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetBucketLocation
                  - s3:ListBucket
                Resource:
                  - arn:aws:s3:::your-cloudtrail-logs-bucket
                  - arn:aws:s3:::your-cloudtrail-logs-bucket/*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: cloudtrail:UpdateTrail
                Resource: '*'
  EventRule789:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: Event rule for DynamoDB PutItem
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.dynamodb
        detail-type:
          - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - dynamodb.amazonaws.com
          eventName:
            - PutItem
        resources:
          - !Sub arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${TableName}
      State: ENABLED
      RoleArn: !GetAtt EventBridgeRole789.Arn
      Targets:
        - Arn: !Sub arn:aws:states:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stateMachine:${StateMachineName}
          Id: StepFunctionTarget
          RoleArn: !GetAtt EventBridgeRole789.Arn
        - Arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - MyEventRuleLogGroup789
              - Arn
          Id: LogGroupTarget

  MyEventRuleLogGroup789:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup

  CloudTrail789:
    Type: AWS::CloudTrail::Trail
    Properties:
      IsLogging: true
      IsMultiRegionTrail: true
      IncludeGlobalServiceEvents: true
      CloudWatchLogsLogGroupArn: !Sub arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:kjgfdxpoikiuuuji-MyEventRuleLogGroup789-ccWZ1hbXC6M6:*
      CloudWatchLogsRoleArn: !GetAtt CloudTrailRole789.Arn
      S3BucketName: demo-buckt-0001
      EventSelectors:
        - DataResources:
            - Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
              Values:
                - !Sub arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${TableName}
          IncludeManagementEvents: true
          ReadWriteType: All
  
 

Parameters:
  StateMachineName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the Step Function state machine to invoke
  TableName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the DynamoDB table to monitor

Outputs:
  EventRuleName:
    Description: Event Rule Name
    Value: !Ref EventRule789
```

I had tried developing a cloudformation template in yaml that creates an event rule that calls a step function when new row is added to dynamodb table. I had also added iam roles for eventbridge and cloudtrail. I also created log groups for this. However, even after updating items to dynamodb table, step function is not getting executed. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you looked at Dynamo Streams?